# Shilft + Enter without inserting new line

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to send a textarea's data when user presses <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>enter</kbd>, but without inserting a new line.

This doesn't work:

```
    $( 'form textarea' ).keydown(function (event) {
        if (event.keyCode == 13 && event.shiftKey) {
            send_data();
            event.preventDefault();
            return false;
        }
     });
```

I'm using Google Chrome.

Comment: works fine here http://jsfiddle.net/ukXEj/

Comment: but doesn't work here http://jsfiddle.net/ukXEj/2/ , do you know why?

Comment: Because it has `alert`, if you replace it with `console.log` it works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While I was debugging, my send_data function was:

```
function send_data() {
    alert('working...');
}
```

But after I saw Esailija's comment I realized my code was correct
and the "alert" was the cause of my problem. Stupid question, sorry for that.

Answer (score 1):

try the following:

```
$( 'form textarea' ).keydown(function (event) {
    if (event.keyCode == 13 && event.shiftKey) {
        event.preventDefault();
        send_data();

        return false;
    }
});
```